# How to use Error.captureStackTrace in node.js

Tags: node.js

Lately I'm going through the implementation of Global Error Handling Middleware in node.js.
Then, I came across this Error.captureStackTrace(this,this.constructor).

**I have checked the Node documentation & found that - Creates a .stack property on targetObject, which when accessed returns a string representing the location in the code at which Error.captureStackTrace() was called.**

**MDN Docs - Maintains proper stack trace for where our error was thrown**

**appError.js File**

```
class AppError extends Error {
constructor(message, statusCode) {
super(message);

this.statusCode = statusCode;

 // Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
}}
```

**app.js File**

```
const AppError = require('./appError');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.all('*', (req,res,next) => {
         const custErr = new AppError('Mentioned Route is not available on server','404');
         next();
})
```

My Observations when I tried to debug the code:

1. I found that .stack property is available on the custErr object even though I have commented the
   Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor) in appError.js file.
2. I'm still confused how to leverage the Error.captureStackTrace()

Can someone explain me on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing you need to understand is that apart from instances of the `Error`-classs the `throw`-statement can also throw [other types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw#Description). Consider this for example:

```js
function throwSomeObj() {
    throw {statusCode: 500};
}

try {
  throwSomeObj();
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(err.stack);
}
```

The exception that is thrown yields the object you passed to it, i.e. `{statusCode: 500}`. Now, as you can see this object does not have any stack-trace, since `undefined` is logged.

However, you can use `Error.captureStackTrace` to capture the stack-trace where you throw the error. Consider this:

```js
function throwObjWithStacktrace() {
    const someError = {statusCode: 500}
    Error.captureStackTrace(someError)
    throw someError;
}


try {
    throwObjWithStacktrace();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.stack);
}
```

As you can see, now `err` contains the stack property and contains the stack to the function where the error was thrown.

Note that when instantiating a new `Error`-object the stack will automatically be set on that object.

Comment: Thank You ! I have understood the concept. But as you said that, when instantiating a new Error-object (custErr) the stack will automatically be set on that object in that case why do we need to use  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor) in the AppError file ? We can even directly access the error stack trace using custErr.stack.

Comment: Ok Undestood now ! The reason for using Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor) in AppError class is becuase the stack trace shouldn't contain the constructor call. Perfect ! You showed me the path @eol

Answer (score -1):

You can add this to your package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

So Today I got this error so what you have to do is follow these steps.

first of all, kill your ports by using npx kill-port 8000
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QEPL.png)

1. check you have installed all the dependencies.(reinstall them)
2. In my case I have reinstalled all the dependencies.
3. and if the error still persists, reinstall the node.
   [see this now after following all the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK8J0.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had set the wrong path, so the node did not find the right path and what I did was:

1. Moved my src folder into my server folder.
2. Executed node again: node src/server.mjs
3. Done, server up and running.